# Simulate Mouse Click error

Tags: vb.net, cursor

I try to make an app whitch will make mouse to go to external points on desktop.
I have a problem with this application. I receive error then press the button:

> A call to PInvoke function 'WindowsApplication1!WindowsApplication1.Form1::mouse_event' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Code is:

```
 Public Declare Auto Function SetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" _
        (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As Long Public 

 Declare Auto Function GetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" _
        (ByRef lpPoint As Point) As Long Public 

 Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" _
       (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, _
        ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long) 

 Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2 ' left button down 
 Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4 ' left button up

 SetCursorPos(x, y) 'moves cursor to x,y position

 mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0) 'Invoke mouse down event
 mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0) 'Invoke mouse up event
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty self-explainable error.

> *"...PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature..."*

Change your code to this:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
Public Shared Sub mouse_event(dwFlags As Integer, dx As Integer, dy As Integer, dwData As Integer, dwExtraInfo As IntPtr)
End Sub
```

[mouse_event function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using the API declaration type of VB6, that does not have any advantage compared with the `DLLImport`, and also you've to update the signature for .NET, change all those Longs for Integers.

Secondly, the `mouse_event` function has been superseded by the `SendInputs` method as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says, and recommends the usage of the new method.

So, as a suggestion, you could stop worriying about your P/invoking and use my [SendInputs Helper Class](http://foro.elhacker.net/net/libreria_de_snippets_compartan_aqui_sus_snippets-t378770.0.html;msg1921592#msg1921592) which provides easy-of-use methods to set the mouse position and to simulate a mouse-button click.

Example usage:

```
SendInputs.MousePosition(100, 500)
SendInputs.MouseClick(SendInputs.MouseButton.LeftPress)
```